# How to install image-upload module in angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to install image-upload module in my angular project for this I am running 
*npm install angular2-image-upload --save* commmand but it showing thsese errors

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR! Could not install from
>   "node_modules\angular2-image-upload" as it does not contain a
>   package.json file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it works well. where did you run this command

Comment: in my gitbash command

Comment: what is the folder?

Comment: my project folder is profile

Comment: and I was inside the profile directory while I run the command

Comment: that has a package.json file?

Comment: yes inside root directory package.json file is there

Comment: That's strange, because i am able to set it up

Comment: then is there any solution?

Comment: delete your node modules and try again

Comment: which node module?

Comment: inside your profile folder, delete whatever inside your node_modules. do npm i

Comment: all node modules?

Comment: yes since you already have a package.json it will be installed again

Comment: even it is showing same error i.e., npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\angular2-image-upload" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be the project you created, try to create a new project using

**`ng new profile`**

and then do

**`npm install angular2-image-upload --save`**